# Как расположить div-ы с помощью bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap, asp.net-core

нужно сделать вот такой макет

[image: Макет]

Navbar есть.

Под ним стандартный

```
<div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr/>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2018</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Нужно вставить вот такой макет (каряво нарисованный конечно)
между navbar (сверху чёрная полоска) и div-ом с @RenderBody() c с помощью bootstrap.

Причём левый и правый блоки (синие) должны быть зафиксированные.

Перепробовал кучу вариантов, но не чего не получилось.
То левый перескакивает куда-та, то правый исчезает. То вообще всё в столбик выстраивается.
**HELP!!!**

Сделал вот так

[image: макет]

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="row center-block">
        <div id="leftDiv" style="background-color: aqua; " class="col-lg-2">
            left div
        </div>
        <div style="background-color: darkgoldenrod;" class="col-lg-8">

            <div style="background-color: crimson;" class="col-lg-6">
                Название
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: crimson;" class="col-lg-6">
                Начальник
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: darkgrey;" class="col-lg-6">
                имущество
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: darkgrey;" class="col-lg-6">
                сотрудники
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="rightDiv" style="background-color: aqua;" class="col-lg-2">
            right div
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Но не пойму как зафиксировать синие блоки по краям, что бы они были до конца экрана и не двигались как navbar до footera. И серый в центре был тоже до конца экрана до footera.

Comment: Версия бутстрапа какая? Третья или четвёртая? По умолчанию с шаблоном asp.net core идёт пока ещё третья, но может вы уже обновили ручками до четвёртой?

Comment: @AK не версия 3 не чего не обновлял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #000000;
}
main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: #ffeeee;
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  flex: 0 1 30%;
  background-color: #aaccff;
}

section {
  flex: 1 0 40%;
  background-color: #ffff00;
}

section nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

section article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

section article div {
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<header class="header"></header>
<main>
  <aside class="aside-left">
    
  </aside>
  <section>
    <nav></nav>
    <article>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </article>
  </section>
  <aside class="aside-right">
    
  </aside>
</main>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что можно было и штатными блоками бутстрапа обойтись. Объявить что row делится на три col, а в средний col вложить ещё раз row, разделив его на два.

Comment: Согласен, я просто в бутстрапе не силен, поэтому сделал нативно

Comment: @AlexandrTovmach спасибо попробую! Хотя, мне нужно с помощью bootstrapa  сделать.

Comment: @AK  я примерно так делал,  но у меня всё в кучу собиралась и не чего не работало.